# Is there a way to get a genuine windows 8 key anymore?

Tags: windows-8

My computer isn't suitable for windows 10, and it would work on windows 8. On the windows store, only windows 10 seems to be available. I'm sure there must be some way to acquire Windows 8, as surely developers would still be using it for testing purposes.

Comment: What do you mean “isn’t suitable?” Windows 10 should run better on equivalent hardware than any windows 8 installation.

Comment: "*Is there a way to get a genuine windows 8 key anymore?*"..... uh.... How about you check ebay.com for example for Windows 8?

Comment: @Appleoddity - well I just like windows 8 more.

Comment: @ITSnuggles - most likely not genuine.

Comment: Microsoft stop selling Windows 8 keys once Windows 8.1 was release.  Likewise Windows 8.1 keys were no longer sold by Microsoft once Windows 10 was released.  *You can get license keys to previous editions of Windows through third-party resellers.*  You might still find copies being sold by Amazon/ect.

Comment: ...assuming you're willing to take the risk of getting stiffed...

Comment: I've not done it often but I have a client that has purchased many of their Windows Server licenses from eBay, have the documentation, get the COA or equivalent, etc. and I've never had any issues installing or activating or applying Windows Updates or anything to indicate anything was not legal and genuine. Same with Amazon, CDW, etc. so eBay sells both NEW and used stuff but they made the purchases and turned over the details to me afterwards for my part and they still have no issues to this day. It doesn't take a genius to make a purchase and verify it's legit beforehand I suppose.

Comment: [on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313.TR2.TRC1.A0.H0.XWindows+8.1+key.TRS0&_nkw=Windows+8.1+key&_sacat=0) you can still get Windows 8.1 keys